# smartgwt gc overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt, heap-memory, smartgwt

Java + gwt + hibernate => the compilation has no errors
Java + gwt + hibernate + smartgwt = gc overhead limit exceeded
I just add to project.gwt.xml the string "inherits name='com.smartgwt.SmartGwt'/" and get OutOfMemoryError
I've found a work-around of the same error in grails and it says I must vary the heapsize parameter of compiler. I've set in Idea java compiler maximum heap size = 512, 1024 and more, but still doesn't work.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <module rename-to='library'>
      <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
 <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
 <inherits name='com.smartgwt.'/>

<!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
<!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
<!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/> -->
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
<!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->

<!-- Other module inherits                                      -->

<!-- Specify the app entry point class.                         -->
<entry-point class='ru.leti.alexeeva.client.Library'/>

 <!-- Specify the app servlets.                   -->
<servlet path='/server' class='ru.leti.alexeeva.server.LibraryServiceImpl'/>

<!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
<source path='client'/>
<source path='shared'/>

 </module>
```

Comment: Well, gwt has its own compiler and it has its own heap memory settings. 
So I was trying to set java memory settings while error was sent from gwt compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using gwt+smartgwt+hibernate, I've also met this problem. But, recently I haven't this problem.

So do you use ant build and hosted mode?
Here is my build file configuration of jvmarg value both for GWT Compile and java compile.

```
  <!-- add jvmarg -Xss16M or similar if you see a StackOverflowError -->
  <jvmarg value="-Xmx1025M"/> 
  <jvmarg value="-Xms512M"/> 
  <jvmarg value="-Xss16M"/>
```